# Joomla v1.5.14 Admin top menu elements are missing

Tags: joomla

My client has Joomla! ver 1.5.14 installed on the remote server. I logged in using the url /administrator/ with login 'admin'. When landed on the admin page after successful login, I observed that the top menu has only two elements, Site and Help. All other elements like Menus, Content, Components, Extensions etc are not there.
Also I do not find any way to access those elements (menus, components). There are not icons on the screen to access them.

Could someone please help me figure out this issue?

Thanks in advance

Regards,
MulC

EDIT:

Following is the screenshot of the admin page
http://postimage.org/image/youvqynh7/

user admin belogs to the group 'Super Administrator'

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It's very strange that this should happen unless your client has been fiddling with the core Joomla files or database tables.

1. Update the site to the latest version of the 1.5 series (1.5.26)
2. Download the full Joomla package, extract the administrator, components, includes, libraries, modules and plugins folder, zip them up and upload to the server, replacing the current folder. Not to worry, this will only override the core files which I assume haven't been edited.
3. Try downloading and installing another admin template.

Else the only other thing I can think of is reconstructing the website which might take a while, depending on the amount of work that went into it.

Comment: Thanks for your response..I have provided some additional information in the original post. Could you please refer it and guide me? Thanks

Comment: @user993923 - please can you upgrade to Joomla 1.5.26, and see if the problem still occurs. I don't see why the site is still running on 1.5.14.

Answer (score 0):

In Joomla! 1.5.x a common security step was to create an alternate "super user" and downgrade the default `admin` account to a standard registered. Due to issues in early versions of 1.5 though it wasn't recommended to delete or disable this account.

This sounds like what is going on with your `admin` account.

You can check this by looking at the database checking the table `jos_users` look for the username `admin` and see what it's `usertype` is set to. At the same time look for a user that has an `usertype` of `Super Administrator` (yes, really the words *Super Administrator*).

Once you have the `username` of the Super Administrator, you will need to find the password. If the client doesn't know it then you will [have to recover the admin password](http://docs.joomla.org/How_do_you_recover_your_admin_password%3F).

Comment: Thanks for your response..I have provided some additional information in the original post. Could you please refer it and guide me? Thanks